# Insert datetime into SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I'm trying to insert values into `datetime` columns from code behind.

In my local compute it works fine, but when the application is on the server it gives me an error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

**I tried this method:** (`add_avent.start` and `add_avent.end` are `datetime`)

```
public void add_event(act_event add_avent)
{
   using (SqlConnection con = connect("igroup20_test2ConnectionString"))
   {
      using (SqlCommand cmd = create_command(con, "insert into act_events values(@e_name, @e_start, @e_end, @e_description, @e_address)"))
      {
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e_name", add_avent.name);

          SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@e_start", SqlDbType.DateTime);
          param2.Value = add_avent.start;
          cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

          SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@e_end", SqlDbType.DateTime);
          param3.Value = add_avent.end;
          cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);

          //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@e_start", SqlDbType.DateTime));
          //cmd.Parameters["@e_start"].Value = add_avent.start;

          //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@e_end", SqlDbType.DateTime));
          //cmd.Parameters["@e_end"].Value = add_avent.end;

          //cmd.Parameters["@e_end"].Value = DateTime.Parse(end);

          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e_description", add_avent.description);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e_address", add_avent.address);

          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }

       //using (SqlCommand cmd2=create_command
   }
}
```

I also tried the method in the comment section which gives me the same error

```
///cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@e_start", SqlDbType.DateTime));
//cmd.Parameters["@e_start"].Value = add_avent.start;

//cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@e_end", SqlDbType.DateTime));
//cmd.Parameters["@e_end"].Value = add_avent.end;
```

Comment: check your server date time format

Comment: I think your format may be wrong. Have you tried yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: You shouldn't be using a format *at all*. You shouldn't be dealing with text - you should *just* keep them as DateTime values. If that's still giving the same issue, please show *exactly* where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Why are you putting your dates ToString? They're dates, leave them that way.

Comment: Are the DateTimes nullable? Besides, the formatted strings are never used.

Comment: I'm not using format at all, check it again. forget about the lines above (I deleted them in the edit). I'm trying to send add_avent.start and add_avent.end which are DateTime variables.

Answer (score 1):

The format should be MM-dd:

```
String start = add_avent.start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
String end = add_avent.end.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

The sql server date format and your system date format are different .so you got this problem.

```
param2.Value =Convert.ToDateTime(add_avent.start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
param2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(add_avent.end.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
```